# Converting Angularjs to Vuejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, socket.io

I am uplifting a chat application from AngularJS to VueJS and I don't have much clue about how the AngularJS. There isn't really a great resources available on AngularJS right now to gain some insight.
If someone could help me in this I'd really appreciate it.

I wish to convert this below AngularJS code to VueJS completely.

```
var app = angular.module('IBMfinder', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', 
function($routeProvider, settings) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/main', {
    templateUrl: 'welcome.html',
    controller: 'welcomeCtrl',
  })
  .when('/find', {
    templateUrl: 'find.html',
    controller: 'findCtrl',
  })
  .when('/chat', {
    templateUrl: 'chat.html',
    controller: 'chatCtrl',
  })

  .otherwise({
    templateUrl: 'welcome.html',
    controller: 'welcomeCtrl',
  })
}])

app.controller('userCount', ['$scope', 'socket', function($scope, 
socket){
  socket.on('userCount', function(amount){
    $scope.online = amount;   
  })
}]);

app.controller('welcomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'settings', 
'socket', function($scope, $location, settings, socket){
$scope.users = 13;
if(settings.getUsername()!==""){
    socket.emit('delete');
    settings.reset();
}

$scope.enter = function(){
    settings.setUsername($scope.name);
    $location.path('/find');
}
}]);

app.controller('findCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'settings', 
'socket', '$rootScope', function($scope, $location, settings, 
socket, $rootScope){
$scope.username = settings.getUsername();

if(!$scope.username || $scope.username == ""){
    location.href = "index.html";
}
if(settings.exists){
    socket.emit('delete');
    location.href = "index.html";

}

$scope.chatlog = [];

if(!settings.exists){
    var username = $scope.username;
    settings.setExists(true);

    socket.emit('new user', username );
};

socket.on('match', function (data) {
    settings.setPartner(data['username'], data['id']);
     $location.path('/chat');
});

}]);


app.controller('chatCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'settings', 
'socket', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$window', '$interval', 
function($scope, $location, settings, socket, $rootScope, $timeout, 
$window, $interval){
var typing = false;
var focus = true;
var titleTimer;
var onFocus = function(){
    focus = true;
    $interval.cancel(titleTimer);
    document.title = 'Chat-Box';
}
var onBlur = function(){
    focus = false;
}
$window.onfocus = onFocus;
$window.onblur = onBlur;   

$scope.username = settings.getUsername();
$scope.partnerTyping = false;

if(!$scope.username || $scope.username == ""){
    location.href = "index.html";
}

$scope.chatlog = [];

if(!settings.exists){
    var username = $scope.username;
    settings.setExists(true);

    socket.emit('new user', username );
};

socket.on('incoming message', function(data){
    if($scope.chatlog[$scope.chatlog.length-1]){
        if($scope.chatlog[$scope.chatlog.length-1].sentby == data.userID){
            $scope.chatlog[ $scope.chatlog.length] = {
                sentby:data.userID,
                chatusername: '',
                chatmessage: data.message
            }
        }else{
            $scope.chatlog[ $scope.chatlog.length] = {
                sentby:data.userID,
                chatusername: data.user + ": ",
                chatmessage: data.message
            }

        }
    }else{
        $scope.chatlog[ $scope.chatlog.length] = {
            sentby:data.userID,
            chatusername: data.user + ": ",
            chatmessage: data.message
        }
    }

    if(!focus){
        document.title = 'New Message!';

        $interval.cancel(titleTimer);
        titleTimer = $interval(function(){
            if(document.title == 'New Message!'){
                document.title = 'Chat-Box';
            }else{
                document.title = 'New Message!';
            }
        }, 1000)
    }

});

socket.on('aborted',  function(data){
    alert('Your partner left, sorry!');
    socket.emit('delete');
    settings.reset();
    location.href = "index.html";
})

$scope.typing = function(){
    if(!typing){
        socket.emit('typing', settings.getID());
        typing = true;
    var stop = $timeout(function() {
        typing = false;
        socket.emit('stop typing', settings.getID());
    }, 2000);

    }


}

socket.on('typing', function(data){
    $scope.partnerTyping = true;
    $('#chatbox').scrollTop(10000);

})

socket.on('stop typing', function(data){
    $scope.partnerTyping = false;
    $('#chatbox').scrollTop(10000);

})


$scope.sendMessage = function(){
    if($scope.message==""){

    }else{
        socket.emit( 'new message', {
            message:$scope.message, 
            partner:$scope.partner,
            partnerID: settings.getID()
        });
    }

    $scope.message = "";        
}

$scope.partner = settings.getPartner();

}]);


app.service('settings', function() {
this.exists = false;
this.username = "";
this.partner = "";
this.partnerID = "";
this.userdata = {}


this.setExists = function(bool){
    this.exists = bool;
}
this.setUsername = function(uname){
    this.username = uname;
}
this.getUsername = function(){
    return(this.username);
}
this.setUserID = function(id){
    this.userdata.id = id;
}
this.getuserdata = function(){
    return(this.userdata);
}
this.setPartner = function(uname, id){
    this.partner = uname;
    this.partnerID = id;
}
this.getPartner = function(){
    return(this.partner);
}
this.getID = function(){
    return(this.partnerID);
}
this.reset = function(){
    this.exists = false;
    this.username = "";
    this.partner = "";
    this.partnerID = "";
    this.userdata = {}
}
});

app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
var socket = io.connect();
return {
on: function (eventName, callback) {
  socket.on(eventName, function () {  
    var args = arguments;
    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
      callback.apply(socket, args);
    });
  });
},
emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
  socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
    var args = arguments;
    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
      if (callback) {
        callback.apply(socket, args);
      }
    });
  })
},
disconnect: function(id){
    socket.disconnect(id);
}
};
});


app.directive('myEnter', function () {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
        if(event.which === 13) {
            scope.$apply(function (){
                scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
};
});

app.directive('schrollBottom', function () {
return {
scope: {
  schrollBottom: "="
},
link: function (scope, element) {
  scope.$watchCollection('schrollBottom', function (newValue) {
    if (newValue)
    {
      $(element).scrollTop(100000);
    }
  });
}
}
})
```

It'd be great if someone could point me to any great resources. I've not had any luck since past week regarding this.

Comment: what are you expecting from the community? to explains that code or to do your job?

Comment: To explain the angularjs code mainly, I got a fair understanding of sockets already. Or to just point me to some resource which would help me understand this code.

Answer (score 2):

Video Tutorials

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM
- https://egghead.io/courses/angularjs-fundamentals

Text Tutorials

- https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Try to search on google first.

If you can't understand something ask a concrete question with an example (it doesn't have to be the full code) so we can help you better.

I don't know if you have experience with Vue.js, I can tell you worse what those tutorials will explain way better. AngularJS uses a different approach than Vue, Angular 2+ or React.

Those frameworks use a component approach so you divide the app into multiple components that have properties.

Angular use an MVC-ish approach, you define modules with angular. module those modules can have external or core dependencies defined in the array.

A module can have a router, a router will define the views and the controller of each view. The views have angular directives and HTML, and the controllers have the logic.

Use one of those tutorials to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for those resources. It certainly helped me a lot.